# How to compare two columns from different data frames that have different number of rows considering another variable

Tags: r

I was trying to compare two columns from different csv files respectively.

But I don't know how to do this since these data frames have different number of rows. In addition, I'd like to compare those with matching another variable.

For example,

```
>dat1
ID    X   Y    CODE 
1111  1   4    A
1111  2   3    A
1111  2   2    A
1112  2   2    A
1112  1   3    A
1112  2   5    A
1121  1   3    B
1121  2   1    B
1121  3   2    B
```

And

```
>dat2
ID    as   df    CODE 
1111   g    a    A
1112   d    d    A
1121   g    b    B
```

Suppose I have those two dataset, I want compare the column `CODE` from `dat1` to `dat2` whether they have each same value with `ID`.

My expectation is like below

```
>dat2
ID    as   df    CODE  Error
1111   g    a    A     0
1112   d    d    A     0
1121   g    b    B     0
```

if any mismatches happen, `dat2$Error` is coded 1. This is my expectation and it would be much better if I know which value is not matched.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: I added a complementary explanation. Thank you.

Comment: You can try with `match` i.e. `dat2$Error <- with(dat2, as.integer(!paste(ID, CODE) %in% paste(dat1$ID, dat1$CODE)))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks! but it shows that 'dat2$Error' have all '1'. Does that work right as I expected?

Comment: Based on the data, I get all 0's

Comment: Same here. Did you negate the first paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1unique <- dat1 %>% select(ID, CODE) %>% distinct() %>% 
    rename(CODE1 = CODE)
dat2 <- dat2 %>% rename(CODE2 = CODE)
dat3 <- right_join(dat1unique, dat2, by = "ID") %>% 
    mutate(Error = ifelse(CODE1 == CODE2, 0, 1))

> dat3
    ID CODE1 as df CODE2 Error
1 1111     A  g  a     A     0
2 1112     A  d  d     A     0
3 1121     B  g  b     B     0
```

Answer (score 0):

if_else((!paste(dat2$ID, dat2$CODE) %in% paste(dat1$ID, dat1$CODE),0,1)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!